# What are the procedures for upgrading a ProLiant ML370 G5 firmware REMOTELY? I'm thinking via its iLO, and if so, where do I access to do the upgrade

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, firmware

What are the procedures for upgrading a ProLiant ML370 G5 firmware REMOTELY? I'm thinking via its iLO, and if so, where do I access to do the upgrade. Firmware files are already on the server's C: drive.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 4):

**You don't even need the ILO for this.**

- If you have access to the operating system, you don't actually need to do this through the ILO.
- You can download the [HP Service Pack for ProLiant DVD .ISO](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx) to the server and run it, following the [instructions](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx#tab=TAB4) along the way.
- You can download the individual firmware updates for that platform piecemeal from the [ML370 G5 software download page](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=1121419&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4064) and follow the [instructions](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=1121419&swItemId=MTX_505fcd943006411b84b08c842e&swEnvOid=4064#tab3) along the way (*this assumes the use of Windows 2008 R2*).

The installation instructions usually look something like:

> To update firmware from Windows operating system on target server:
>
> 1. Place the Smart Component in a temporary directory.
> 2. From the same directory, run the Smart Component by double-clicking it.
> 3. When the Smart Component dialog window displays, click the Install button to initiate the firmware upgrade.
> 4. Reboot your system if you would like the update to take effect immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the IP to the iLO in question?  Do you know the credentials?

If not, you'll need to use one of the following methods, up to and including powering off the server and using the dip switch block on the motherboard:

http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0115524

Then access the iLO via https on the IP you have set with the credentials you set.

The virtual media tab in the left hand menu will permit you to mount the update DVD you can get with your HP support contract.  It will autorun the updates once you reboot.

Answer (score 1):

If all files are already there then just use **Remote Console** and execute firmware update.